# Explorer crashed on Windows 8 Deep Freeze will erase all my data if restarted and Task Manager is not coming up

Tags: windows, backup

How do I force explorer to restart without the task manager or Ctrl Alt del?

Neither are responding to any input and Windows is just completely unresponsive.

Deep Freeze (configured by admins) will remove any data once the device restarts and I have critical data on here that I will lose if I do not back it up somehow (I was in the middle of backing it up and explorer crashed)

What are some solutions I could try at this point?

Comment: Call a admin to remotly restart explorer. Use the deepfreeze thawed space next time, or a network drive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to restart the explorer without task manager but you can log-off your user and login again can start the explorer.exe (in deep freeze it will only reboot if it is restarted or shutdown) so this may not cause you to loose your data. But take yagmoth555's comment as priority and ask your admin to thaw a drive for you to save it in case of any emergency.Kindly text in comment if you found this is useful.